# How to specify with a parameter a field to extract from a RECORD variable

Tags: postgresql, functions, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

Here's a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_heights (id INT, height REAL);
INSERT INTO t_heights VALUES (1,53.63), (2,45.19), (3,47.06);
```

Reading through the table rows with a FOR...LOOP and a RECORD type variable like this works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnct_row_by_row (input_table regclass) 
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
    current_row RECORD;

BEGIN
FOR current_row IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '||input_table
        LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'field value: %',current_row.height; -- *<<< hardcoded field name*
        END LOOP;
END;
$$
;
```

Results:

```
SELECT fnct_row_by_row ('t_heights') ;
NOTICE:  field value: 53.63
NOTICE:  field value: 45.19
NOTICE:  field value: 47.06
```

However, the field extracted from the RECORD variable needs to have its name hardcoded.

**How to specify dynamically the field to be extracted?**

The following generates an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnct_row_by_row2 (input_table regclass, input_field_name TEXT) 
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
    current_row RECORD;

BEGIN

FOR current_row IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '||input_table
        LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE 'specified field: %',current_row.input_field_name; -- *<<< field name from parameter*
        END LOOP;
END;
$$
;
```

Execution:

```
SELECT fnct_row_by_row2 ('t_heights','height') ;
ERROR:  record "current_row" has no field "input_field_name"
CONTEXTE : SQL statement "SELECT current_row.input_field_name"
PL/pgSQL function fnct_row_by_row2(regclass,text) line 10 at RAISE
```

Comment: `RAISE NOTICE 'specified field: %',to_jsonb(current_row)->>input_field_name;`?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
        RAISE NOTICE 'specified field: %', input_field_name;
```

It's already a variable at the top. That will work if you want the column/field name. If you want the column's value you'll need to use something that provides a dynamic accessor to a row type. For that, you need.

- jsonb (as mentioned in the comments by Abelisto)
- hstore

That said, This whole thing is a really bad idea. When possible, you should just create a function that processes a *scalar* and run it over the result set.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(a text)
RETURNS text
AS $$
  SELECT 'foo' + a;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT f(x) FROM t;
```

Rather than doing something that's more complex and statically types the table name burried within.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fThatOpensACursor(col text)
RETURNS SETOF text
AS $$
  SELECT to_jsonb(t)->>col
  FROM statically_typed_table AS t;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT fThatOpensACursor('t.myCol');
```

Comment: Thanks @Evan Carroll, but replacing current_row.input_field_name with input_field_name alone just prints the field name, not its value that changes for each row.

Comment: could you please be a bit more explicit about your proposed solution SELECT myFunction(t.myCol) FROM t; ?

Comment: @SébastienClément updated.

Comment: My example was just a part, for clarity, of a larger function where I loop through each row of a table and use some of the columns' values from that row to compare to a second table and return each time a new computed dataset. Thanks for your suggestion, but it's not clear to me how it applies.